# AXI4 address calculation for INCR bursts

Tags: axi4

I'm going through the AXI4 specification at https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0022/d/IHI0022D_amba_axi_protocol_spec.pdf. On page A3-47, a number of equations for calculating addresses are given:

> These equations determine addresses of transfers within a burst:
>
> - Start_Address =AxADDR
> - Number_Bytes = 2 ^ AxSIZE
> - Burst_Length =AxLEN+1
> - Aligned_Address = (INT(Start_Address / Number_Bytes) ) x Number_Bytes.
>
> This equation determines the address of the first transfer in a burst:
>
> - Address_1 = Start_Address.
>
> For an INCR burst, and for a WRAP burst for which the address has not wrapped, this equation determines the address of any transfer after the first transfer in a burst:
>
> - Address_N = Aligned_Address + (N – 1) × Number_Bytes

However, unless I missed something, the spec does not put restrictions on the Start_Address to be aligned to the size of each transfer for INCR bursts, while it does state it explicitly for WARP bursts. Thus, the Address_N formula would seem to be incorrect for a Start_Address that is not aligned to Number_Bytes in an INCR burst with Burst_Length > 1.

Did I miss something? Is the spec incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would like to mention that the link I posted was for an outdated version of the specification. This was adding further confusion because the pseudo code for transfers in the outdated version also suggests that an unaligned address remains unaligned for INCR bursts. The newest version, which can be found [here](https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0022/g/IHI0022G_amba_axi_protocol_spec.pdf), makes it clear that the intention is for subsequent addresses to be aligned, both in the equations for calculating addresses and in the pseudo code listing.

However, there still remains a slight inconsistency in the explanation for INCR bursts as shown in the following paragraph on page A3-50 (of version g) of the spec.

> In an incrementing burst, the address for each transfer in the burst is an increment of the address for the previous transfer. The increment value depends on the size of the transfer. **For example, the address for each transfer in a burst with a size of 4 bytes is the previous address plus four**.

This suggests that the increment is always fixed. However, if the start address is unaligned, then this is not true for the first increment. That is, the increment between Address_2 and Address_1 will be strictly less than Number_Bytes.

This is a minor oversight but it left me scratching my head for a while. I sent this issue as an errata item and got told that it would be considered for later revisions of the spec, which seems to indicate that ARM thinks this is a valid issue. Hence I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Page A3-51 section **Unaligned transfers** explicitly states that this is allowed. There follow several examples of unaligned transfers.

Note that it also says that the slave does not have to take special action, which I read as the slave is allowed to ignore the LS address bits.

Thus you can do a 32-bit read from address 0x01 and you get back 32-bits. But the slave can still read the location 0 as well. This has no impact on e.g. memory, but if the location is a set of four FIFO's the reading of location 0 has an impact!